# Allow same dates for different names in a MongoDB collection?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have one MongoDB doc:

```
{
    "asset": "BANANA",
    "timeframe": "5m",
    "date": "2020-07-11T03:55:00.000Z"
}
```

The date is critical for me. There can only be one date entry per `asset` with the same date. So on the next stage, my fresh data comes in and before it goes into the db, it looks like this:

```
{
    "asset": "BANANA",
    "timeframe": "5m",
    "date": "2020-07-11T03:55:00.000Z"
}
{
    "asset": "BANANA",
    "timeframe": "5m",
    "date": "2020-07-11T04:00:00.000Z"
}
```

So as you can see, now I have two records on their way to be submitted into the MongoDB database. At this stage, I perform a test to see which one of those is already in the db and which are new.

I'm using the following query `model.exists({date: "2020-07-11T03:55:00.000Z"})`

This removes the `"2020-07-11T03:55:00.000Z"` object from the incoming data and only proceeds to store the one that is new, the one with the `"date": "2020-07-11T04:00:00.000Z"` signature.

So my db looks like this now:

```
{
    "asset": "BANANA",
    "timeframe": "5m",
    "date": "2020-07-11T03:55:00.000Z"
}

{
    "asset": "BANANA",
    "timeframe": "5m",
    "date": "2020-07-11T04:00:00.000Z"
}
```

However, on the next data received, I get the following in the response:

```
{
    "asset": "APPLE",
    "timeframe": "5m",
    "date": "2020-07-11T03:55:00.000Z"
}
```

When I perform my search, `model.exists({date: "2020-07-11T03:55:00.000Z"})`, this fresh data is flagged as already existing despite the fact that the asset is a new `"asset"` with the `"APPLE"` value in there.

Is there a way to return `exists:true` for:
`"asset": "BANANA", "date": "2020-07-11T03:55:00.000Z"` but `exists:false` for `"asset": "APPLE", "date": "2020-07-11T03:55:00.000Z"`?

Stopping same-date entries on same assets but allowing same-data entries for different assets.

I also will make sure that my MongoDB Schema does NOT have `{data: unique}` in there.

The solution I thought of, is probably creating a third UUID identifier based on the `data` and the `asset` values but that somehow feels a bit overcomplicated?

Comment: why are you not specifying `asset` as well in your insert query. Looks like a simple `upsert` should do.

Comment: Yes. It worked. I, somehow, thought it would be a lot more complicated to solve this. It was that simple indeed.